# Letter 'b' rendering as UTF-8 Control in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, utf-8

I am grabbing an authenticated user name:

```
var username = '<%= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>'
```

And simply assigning it to an element:

```
$('#displayname').val(username.substring(5).toLowerCase());
```

When the `username` starts with a 'b', it renders as a white rectangle, like a UTF-8 control:

[Character Table](https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm)

Here is an example:

[image]

What is this?

Comment: Could you check what character it is that? For every `b` (also created by you)? Other characters look like `b`.

Comment: When I just alert(`username`) for this user, it shows the square. It's like the username it is grabbing from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` looks this way.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi So, the value directly from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` looks this way.

Comment: I have confirmed that other 'b' characters are fine, but if they come at the start of this string, they render this way. Also, 'b' is the only problem character so far.

Comment: We need to know what it is the character. Try displaying `username.substring(5).toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0);` and `username.charCodeAt(0);`. I suspect that there is an extra non-visible character coming in username, which interact badly when calling with `.lower()`

Comment: Also, your code assumes that you can jump into the string (of UTF-16 code units) at position 5. Why is that known to be the right position and not in the middle of two code units that encode one Unicode codepoint (say, as smiley)?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi `username.substring(5).toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0)` returns 8.

Comment: @TomBlodget Hi Tom. The string I am jumping into always has the same 5 characters at the start of the string. I am only interested in grabbing everything after that.

Comment: 8 is also `\b`. So I think somewhere you add an extra backslash `\` on processing username. You should go down in this path, to debug and find the problem

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes, the markup is interpreting \b in this string as one character, with character code 8. For my purpose, the \ and the b should be separate characters. I will look into that

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I am just going to do `username.replace('\b','b')` May not be perfect, but it works. I will accept your help as the answer if you add an answer. Thank you!

Comment: It is not an answer (it will not help others). Could you check if there are error with names starting with `r` and `n`: `\r` and `\n`? These are other escape sequences.